# Correlation or dependence between NDVI and pollution data sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dataset, predictor

Is there any statistical test or measure to evaluation the degree of correlation or dependence between two sets of data-points ?
First set is represented by NDVI values in each pixel and second set is pollution data e.g. distance from source and concentration. 
Thanks!

Comment: if you have two sets of data points, you can use correlation coefficients to determine the linear dependency of data.  This is the simplest measure of dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend a rank correlation like Spearman's $\rho$ or Kendall's $\tau$.  These will detect any *monotone* relationship between the two quantities, while Pearson's correlation measures the strength of the *linear* relationship.